# Development Manager KPIs

Tags: kpi

I'm a development manager for a medium sized company.  I've never had specific KPI's before and now I am being given some.  The KPIs I've been given I don't think relate too well to my role.

I would like to know based on other peoples experience what are regular KPIs for a development manager and how are they measured?

Answer (score 3):

Depends what a dev manager is at your company and what their goal is. You KPIs are what you're being measured against and if they are not what you think you're supposed to be doing then I think there may be **a serious mismatch** in either your understanding of your role or your bosses understanding of it.

I would suspect that you have certain SLAs to that you need to adhere to and these would proably be in the KPI list.

What are you managing?

Keeping devs sweet? Delivering Code? Managing outsourcing etc?

Comment: At the moment I'm responsible for developing projects to spec and schedule, keeping my dozen developers happy & project manager, making sure the projects are aligning to business requirements and thinking strategically about the software we purchase and developments we make.

Answer (score 0):

1. Code Coverage (assuming you are doing unit testing)
2. Build Failures
3. Performance Test Results (assuming you have automated test for this)
4. Technical Debt (3rd party usage)

You may find following interesting.

http://blog.yusuftok.net/software-development-kpis/

Answer (score -1):

It might be quite useful for you to check Scrum as an Agile methodology, as it has really clear and transparent to track the performance of the whole team and the development of the project.

I highly recommend you read the [Scrum Guide](http://www.scrum.org/scrumguides/) - a pretty short text introducing you to the terminology, rules and the whole project life cycle using Scrum. You've got not more than 5 artifacts (documents) that help you track your progress, the development of the project and everything else.

Another short intro to Scrum you can find [here](http://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/topics/scrum)